# When to analyze columns?

Tags: postgresql, statistics, maintenance

I have a table with millions of records. Before select, I run Analyze table (col1, col2).

We want to reduce cost, since a lot of IO operations happen in AWS Aurora.

Should I run analyze only when we know data has changed substantially? Or is it always required to run, even if only some data has changed?

Answer (score 4):

Normally, you should not need to run `ANALYZE` yourself. This is done automatically by autovacuum. If you find that your statistics are not good enough in some cases, you should tune autoanalyze for the affected tables so that it runs more often or collects more data.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL automatically analyzes the table based on the settings of autovacuum_analyze_threshold and autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor.  Normally the table would be analyzed automatically when the table has turned over 10%.  If this is not enough, it would be better to change those settings than to constantly run ANALYZE by hand.

But there are some situations where the automatic system doesn't work adequately.

- You have just created an expressional index.
- You have just created custom statistics using `CREATE STATISTICS`.
- You have just set `statistics` or `n_distinct` using `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN col_name ...`.
- You have just changed `default_statistics_target`.
- It is a `TEMPORARY` table.  Temp tables cannot be seen by other sessions, including the autovacuum "session".

Also, if you just completed some kind of bulk update or bulk importation, the table should be analyzed automatically, but you might not want to wait for it to kick in and then finish.  If you want to know definitely that it has been done before you move on, then it makes sense to run VACUUM ANALYZE manually.